# How do I align the text of a label and button after creating one at runtime in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have looked at a couple different versions similar to what I need but none of the answers is what I'm looking for. I am trying to create a new entry in this TableLayoutPanel for adding and removing users for a system. I am trying to add a button and a label. I have successfully created the button and the label but when I go to run it, they are top left aligned. I am trying to center align them so it looks like the other table entries. Below is the code I have and the output the new entry should be aligned with.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserTable.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 14));
    UserTable.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "user5" }, 0, 5);
    UserTable.Controls.Add(new Button() { Text = "remove" }, 1, 5);
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: All of the code that the designer generates is available to look at. You can just copy what the designer does.

Comment: The designer doesn't have the alignment information.

Comment: Where is it then?

Answer (score 0):

@Rema Thomas.

For centering them looks like the other table entries, you can try the following code.
You can also refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-anchor-and-dock-child-controls-in-a-tablelayoutpanel-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to set according to the specific situation.

```
        Button button4;
        Label label4;
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserTable.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 14));
            this.button4 = new Button() { Text = "remove" };
            this.label4 = new Label() { Text ="user3"};
            UserTable.Controls.Add(this.button4, 1, 3);
            UserTable.Controls.Add(this.label4, 0, 3);
            this.label4.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
            label4.AutoSize = true;
            this.button4.Anchor = ((AnchorStyles)((AnchorStyles.Left |AnchorStyles.Right))); 
        }
```

[image]